# I want to make a blacklist command that blocks an invite from a specific guild discord.py

Tags: database, discord, command, discord.py, blacklist

I'm pretty new to all of this. I want to make a command that blocks user from sending a link from blacklisted guild.
The command would look like this:
*!blacklist (guild id) reason*
This is the code so far

```
async def server_blacklist(ctx, guild_id: int,*,reason= "no reason provided"):
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    invitelink = await delete_invite(guild)
```

My 1st thought is that I need to store the guild ids somehow ( in .txt or .db ). But I don't know how.

Comment: Do you want to blacklist invites in general? Every invite contains `discord.gg` , you could just simply blacklist that.

Comment: No, I want to blacklist a specific guild by it's id. So when someone breaks a rule. I can blacklist him 2

Comment: But you can't find out if a user is from the Guild or not, can you? I don't know if your method is possible. From this point of view, he can also come from another server and your desired method would block his links just because he is on the blacklisted server, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yeah, but that is not the point. I want to blacklist an invite from a server using server-id. So when the user sends an invite to that server. It deletes it @Dominik

Comment: Every invite is different/unique. You are not able to fetch the created invites if your bot is not on the server. Simply blacklist `discord.gg` and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was unsatisfying, so here's a new one: If you wanna write to files, I suggest [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

And a more thorough explanation of the method of blacklisting a certain guild:

The method I found that you could use for blacklisting just certain guilds is much simpler than I thought before, invite objects have a guild property, so you can easily check.

A "simple" example of how to do what you want to do is:

```py
@client.command()
async def server_blacklist(ctx, guild_id: int):  # Blacklisting command
    # To add a guild id to the file:
    with open("blacklisted guilds.txt", "a") as blacklistfile:  # Open file in append mode
        blacklistfile.write(f"{guild_id}\n")  # Add a new line with the guild id


@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # Event that triggers every time a message is sent
    if "discord.gg" in message.content:  # Check if message has "discord.gg"
        inviteid = message.content.split("discord.gg/")[1].split(" ")[0]  # Get the invite id from the link
        invite = await client.fetch_invite(inviteid)  # Get the invite object from the id
        guild_id = invite.guild.id  # Get the guild id
        # To retrieve the guild ids and check against another
        with open("blacklisted guilds.txt", "r") as blacklistfile:  # Open file in reading mode
            for idstring in blacklistfile.read().split("\n"):  # Start iterating through all the lines
                if not idstring == "":  # Check if line has content
                    if int(idstring) == guild_id:  # Check if the id from the file is the same as guild_id
                        await message.delete()
                        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}! Don't send invites to that server here!")
                        break  # Stop the for loop, since we have already matched the guild id to a blacklisted one

    await client.process_commands(message)  # When using the on_message event and commands, remember to add this, so that the commands still work
```

Comment: Thanks you. Gonna try it out and see how it works